# how to convert int part and fraction part of a double into two integers in arduino

Tags: c, int, double, arduino

How to convert in Arduino or C for example 30.8365146 into two integers: 30 and 8365146.

This problem faces me when i try to send gps data via xbee series 1 which don't allow to transmit fraction numbers, so i decided to split the data into two parts. how can i do this?

```
  double num=30.233;
  int a,b;
  a = floor(num); 
  b= (num-a) * pow(10,3);
```

output: 30 and 232 !!!
 the output is not 30 and 233 why and how can i fix it

```
  double num=30.2334567;
  int a,b;
  a = floor(num); 
  b= (num-a) * pow(10,7);
```

output : 30 and 32767 !!!

Comment: You should first determine exactly how many decimal points you want to turn into the integer. Otherwise you can't get what you want. i.e. 1.30 should return the same two integers as 1.3.

Comment: i have already defined how many decimals i want by multiplying the fraction number in the first example by 10^3 and in the second by 10^7

Comment: You're going to have slight issues with decimal precision by doing that, additionally...if you input a number 30.2330000 versus 30.233 how do you know to multiply by 10^3 versus 10^7? The answer is you can know, but the program won't know because to the program each number is the same.

Comment: in my case its not a problem because i know the data coming from gps i always 7 decimal points

Comment: If you know that it is always 7 then you would never do `*pow(10,3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this problem may involve rounding error, as suggested by the other answers, I would recommend doing the muliplication of your floating point values first, then subtracting.  For instance, this code prooduced the output you are looking for:

```
int main() {
    double num = 30.233;
    int a,b;
    a = floor(num);
    b = num * pow(10,3) - a * pow(10,3);
    printf("%d",b);

    num = 30.2334567;
    a = floor(num);
    b = num * pow(10,7) - a * pow(10,7);
    printf("%d", b);

    return 0;
}
```

output: 233 and 2334567

Comment: @A Stidham : can you please tell me what is the function of printf("%d", b); return 0; because i tried the code without them and the output is correct except for the last digit the output : 233 and 2334560

Comment: @A Stidham  : the code works fine for a any fraction digit less than seven digits if the num= 30.233456 it works correctly

Comment: @Abdelrahman Tarief: The function printf("%d", b) prints the value of the variable b to the console.  I included it just to verify my algorithm inside my test program.  As for return 0, that indicates that the main method of my test program exited without error and is not necessary for the program run.

Comment: @Abdelrahman Tarief:  Here is helpful link explaining the printf function and its format specifiers, i.e. %d, %f, etc.  http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output

Comment: @A Stidham : so you don't know why there is error in the seventh digit and the code works correctly with 6 digits

Comment: @Abdelrahman Tarief: No.  The code works fine even for the seventh digit on my machine.  I'll let you know if I come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

What you are facing seems to be a double precision problem. The number you are writing to the variable is not representable, so the compiler takes the closest one.

Your algorithm is right.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this to another question you asked on this -- you need a set number of decimal places. A simple function will sort it out.

```
#define PLACES 3

void extract(double x, int *a, int *b, int *n)
{
    char buf[PLACES+10];

    sprintf(buf, "%.*f", PLACES, x);
    sscanf(buf, "%d.%d", a, b);

    *n = (int) pow(10, PLACES);

    // integer part is a, fractional part b / n
}
```

e.g.

```
    extract(30.2334567, &a, &b, &n);
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, n);

    -> 30, 233, 1000
```

You could take `PLACES` as an integer parameter if you wanted to vary the precision.

Comment: i tried x=30.2334567 and the output is 0 and 14336
note: i take the code copy paste :)

Comment: @AbdelrahmanTarief: it will automatically round the floating point number to `PLACES` decimal places. Remember you need `n`, or you won't be able to distinguish between 1.300 and 1.003.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanTarief: this function isn't returning anything... it's just an example. I'll edit it to allow you to set the variables.

Comment: i really appreciate your help :)

Comment: i hope you didn't get bothered by my stupidity but that exactly what i wrote :  int a,b,n;
      double x=30.2334567;
      extract(x, &a, &b, &n);
      

     
       Serial.println(a);
  Serial.print(b/n);

Comment: @AbdelrahmanTarief: you can't divide b by n or you get a fraction again.

Comment: i tried Serial.print(b); too and it didn't work too :)

Comment: @AbdelrahmanTarief - I've tested it and it works fine, you'll have to examine how you use the variables if you need them in a different format.

Comment: i just print them to the serial monitor on the arduino

Comment: i have got the problem now the serial monitor is not able to display a long number like 2334567 i don't know the reason , any way thanks alot for your help

Comment: @AbdelrahmanTarief - these comments are too long... I can't help any more :) I've posted my output above. Try using PLACES of no more than 3 to see if that works.

Comment: :) ok man i am very thankful for you help